# play framework json reads from empty string to empty list

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Hi everyone recently I faced an issue in converting json into my own data model.

I have a json format message which may contain an empty string:

```
{
    "name" : "John Doe", 
    "hobbies": ""
}
```

or a list of hobby types:

```
{
    "name" : "John Doe", 
    "hobbies": [{"name":"basketball"}]
}
```

And the following is my case class data model in scala play framework:

```
case class Person(name: String, hobbies: List[Hobby])
case class Hobby(name: String)
```

Right now I'm using the default json formatter but of course it's not working well when we have empty string as value.

```
implicit val HobbyJson= Json.format[Hobby]
implicit val PersonJson = Json.format[Person]
```

it will throw exception if the `hobbies` has a empty string. I want to convert it into an empty list when it's the empty string. I search the document Play provides but couldn't find infomation. Can anyone give some suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @millhouse answer, it definitely works. Like he said we need a custom `Reads[Person]` to properly convert it.

I also post my code as reference.

```
  implicit val personJsonReads: Reads[Person] = (
      (__ \ "name").read[String] and
      (__ \ "hobbies").read[List[Hobby]].orElse(Reads.pure(List())) 
  ) (Person.apply _)
```

`read[List[Hobby]].orElse(Reads.pure(List()))` will generate the empty list when the value cannot convert to `List[Hobby]`.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the default `Format` macros won't work for you here because of the inconsistent treatment of `hobbies`. So you need to implement your own `Reads[Person]` - here's how I'd do it:

```
object PersonJson {
  implicit val hobbyConverter = Json.format[Hobby]

  val personReads = new Reads[Person] {

    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Person] = {
      for {
        personName  <- (json \ "name").validate[String]
        hobbies     <- (json \ "hobbies").validate[JsValue]
      } yield {
        val maybeHobbyList = hobbies.validate[List[Hobby]].asOpt
        Person(personName, maybeHobbyList.getOrElse(Nil))
      }
    }
  }

  implicit val personConverter = Format(personReads, Json.writes[Person])
}
```

The key thing to note here is surrounding the whole thing in a `JsResult` courtesy of the for-comprehension and the `yield`. This gives us all the necessary checking (like the `name` field being there and being a String, and the `hobbies` field being there).

The code within the `yield` block only runs if we've got something that looks pretty close to a `Person`. Then we can safely try validating the `hobbies` as a `List[Hobby]`, and convert the result to an `Option[List[Hobby]]`. It'll be a `None` if it didn't work (thus it must have been a string) and so we default it to the empty list as required.